# Can't unzip file with php

Tags: php, file, unzip

I have a folder in my web server were I put zip files that I need to then unzip. I want to do that with php and this is what I have tried but it does not work:

```php
<?php
$file = $_GET["file"];
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($file+'.zip');
$zip->extractTo('./');
$zip->close();
?>
```

The zip files are in the same folder as the php file, but when I go to the php page it does nothing.

By doing some testing I have found out that the script dies on the `$zip = new ZipArchive;` line

How can I manage this to work?

Comment: `the script dies` due to what error...?

Comment: @UmairKhan I do not know that. I just put an echo before each line and the script stops echoing after the first line of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.
The code is fine, but the hosting service is not, and they do not have the ZIP extension available right now

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$fileName = $_GET['file'];  // get file name in the URL param "file"

if (isset($fileName)) {    // if $fileName php variable is set than    


    $zip = new ZipArchive;          // create object
    $res = $zip->open($fileName);   // open archive
    if ($res === TRUE) {
      $zip->extractTo('./');        // extract contents to destination directory
      $zip->close();               //close the archieve    
      echo 'Extracted file "'.$fileName.'"';
    } else {
      echo 'Cannot find the file name "'.$fileName.'" (the file name should include extension (.zip, ...))';
    }
}
else {
    echo 'Please set file name in the "file" param';
}

?>
```

**Note:-** For More Details Please refer https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php

Comment: Please explain your answer rather than just put loads of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Also change `$zip->open($file+".zip");` to `$zip->open($file);`.
**+ (plus sign)** is not concatenation operator in php

```
<?php
    // $_GET["file"] is set to `a.zip`

    $file = $_GET["file"];
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $zip->open($file);
    $zip->extractTo('./');
    $zip->close();
?>
```